# talend: Merge multiple (complex) flat files into single JSON file

Tags: java, json, talend

I'm testing talend for its potential use in a project - basic tasks are completed easily, however I'm struggling with the following sitution:

We have multiple flat files, all of which combine to describe various items. For my testing, I would simply like to merge two of these files (for now) into a JSON format. The catch here is that one of the files contains 1 or more rows per item;

For example:

File 1: id, category

```
1, A   
2, A  
3, B
```

File 2: id, language, colour

```
1, en_GB, Red  
1, de_DE, Rot  
2, en_GB, Blue  
3, en_GB, Green  
3, de_DE, Grün  
3, es_ES, Verde
```

The result should look something like this:

```
{  
  items[{  
    "id": 1,  
    "category": "A",  
    "colours": [{  
      "language": "en_GB",  
      "colour": "Red"  
     }, {  
      "language": "de_DE",  
      "colour": "Rot"  
    }],  
  },  
...  
}
```

What I have tried so far is:

tMap to merge the files/rows together, then tAggregate to group by the id's. This does not quite work, as it results in the language and colour attributes being formatted individually as comma separated lists:

ie.

```
"language": "en_GB, de_DE",  
"colour": "Red, Rot"
```

This is not what we require.

Is it possible to achieve what we need in talend? If so, how?

Comment: for such a niche product, I believe you would get a better faster answer in the company's forum https://www.talendforge.org/forum/

Comment: I think this is a bit tough in Talend since the JSON integration is not very well done. It might be possible to do this with a custom component. Or maybe someone else has another idea how nested field data can be written, I am not aware of such a thing in Talend - Talend works flattened, row based afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution I put together, using java json library, since json components do not handle such complex structure.

[image]

tAggregateRow settings:

[image]

First, load the [json-java.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm) using a tLibraryLoad. Then join data using a tMap (on the id column, returning all matches), then aggregate it using the id, and output a list of objects for language and colour. Then in tJavaFlex, loop over the rows to construct the final json (here's the [java code](https://pastebin.com/7resWXwY)).

This gives the below formatted output, based on your example :

```
{
    items: [{
            "id": 1,
            "category": "A",
            "colours": [{
                    "colour": "Red",
                    "language": "en_GB"
                }, {
                    "colour": "Rot",
                    "language": "de_DE"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "category": "A",
            "colours": [{
                    "colour": "Blue",
                    "language": "en_GB"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "category": "B",
            "colours": [{
                    "colour": "Green",
                    "language": "en_GB"
                }, {
                    "colour": "Grün",
                    "language": "de_DE"
                }, {
                    "colour": "Verde",
                    "language": "es_ES"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you @iMezouar, your solution is very close to what I had already tried. Based on this solution and other comments, I get the impression talend isn't all that great when the data structures are _complicated_.

Comment: Talend has excellent XML support, but when it comes to JSON it isn't as good. JSON components lack the grouping functionality like the one available in XML components, thus the use of an external library to handle it (use of JSONArray and JSONObject to create an array of objects). This will probably be improved in future releases.